# React reuse component in both mobile and desktop view

Tags: reactjs, mobile, desktop, code-reuse

For example I have a **book list component** that I want to reuse. In the mobile is used by a route, in the desktop by another route.

The book list component has links to the book. The tricky part is that the book on **desktop version** has links to the **desktop book page url** while the **mobile version** has links to the **mobile book page url**.

## What is the best option to do this?

#### 1 Have a flag in the book list that says it should render for mobile or desktop;

Example: `<BookList type="large" />`

Example: `<BookList type="small" />`

Pros:

- Easy to use;
- Easy to do, just need some if else;

Cons:

- Not very reusable;

#### 2 Pass the some props like `getBookUrl` which is called by the book list component

Example: `<BookList getBookUrl={(book)=>`/small/book/${book.id}`} />`

Example: `<BookList getBookUrl={(book)=>`/large/book/${book.id}`} />`

Pros:

- Very reusable;

Cons:

- Hard to use the component because you need to prepare that function in the parent and is a pain to do it all the time;

#### 3 Pass the some props like `getBookUrl` (but this function is stored in the book list component) which is called by the book list component

Example: `<BookList getBookUrl={BookList.getBookUrlSmall} />`

Example: `<BookList getBookUrl={BookList.getBookUrlLarge} />`

#### 4 Pass the some props from the book list component

```
BookList.small = {
  getBookUrl: (book)=>`/small/book/${book.id}`,
}
BookList.large = {
  getBookUrl: (book)=>`/large/book/${book.id}`,
}
```

Example: `<BookList {...BookList.small} />`

Example: `<BookList {...BookList.large}/>`

#### 5 Something even better, tell me :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you are making a web app right?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Making components explicitly-configurable (e.g. `"small"` & `"large"`) is one step away from have a responsive component (configures itself based on screen size).

But if your tactic for dealing with mobile is (sometimes) hosting a separate mobile site, this runs against the tactic of mobile components.

Regardless,

without knowing too much about your exact situation, I'd do something like this:

```
// BookListResponsive.js
import isMobile from "mobile-detector-of-my-choice"
import BookList from "./BookList.js"

export default props => isMobile()
    ? <BookList {...props} getUrl={id => `small/${id}`} />
    : <BookList {...props} getUrl={id => `large/${id}`} />
```

It might also be worth checking out react-routers [dynamic routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/responsive-routes)

```
<Media query={PRETTY_SMALL}>
  {screenIsSmall => screenIsSmall
    // small screen has no redirect
    ? <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/invoices/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path="/invoices/:id" component={Invoice}/>
      </Switch>
    // large screen does!
    : <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/invoices/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path="/invoices/:id" component={Invoice}/>
        <Redirect from="/invoices" to="/invoices/dashboard"/>
      </Switch>
  }
</Media>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is a good approach, but I don't prefer having components render differently based on the screen size. I prefer to be crystal clear what is being rendered (easier to maintain/test) from top to down based on props.